# How can i restart thread session during the test time in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have only one problem
I do a load test with JMeter
I send a request to IP with 15 threads in 5 minutes
This IP is virtual
There are 2 real services in the back
we turn off service 1 and turn on service 2 during the test time, it does not direct to the service 2
sessions do not restart
There is no response to requests.

How can I do it

It happens when I do it with soapui

Comment: Is this the problem of Jmeter or must i check something else? Maybe Jmeter has any parameter i have to add

When i do this test with soapui if i kill my sessions it creates a new session, but with JMeter it does not

it doesn't change sending a request to service 2 while the test doesn't redirect requests from service 1 to service 2.

Comment: I send requests 15 threads 5 minutes during to virtual IP (for example 1.1.1.1)
I see all the requests and response
I see 15 sessions have been created on the system
After 1 minute I change the active node to the standby node in the load balancer (turn off active nod, turn on standby nod)

Comment: I see JMeter waiting. It does not send requests and does not response (it wait for example 10 minute)
When I kill my session on the system
Did not create a new session on the system
But JMeter wait. It doesn't create a new session and is not here new requests and response
When I do it with Soapui everything is ok.

Comment: It wait approximately 3-5 second and again send new request
When I kill my session on the system
It Create a new session on the system

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's happening due to [caching of the underlying IP address on JVM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html) or OS level.

Try adding [DNS Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan and set it to use a custom DNS resolver, it should enable resolution of the underlying IP address by each thread separately so you should start getting responses from the new IP.

More information: [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem of Jmeter or must i check something else? Maybe Jmeter has any parameter i have to add When i do this test with soapui if i kill my sessions it creates a new session, but with JMeter it does not it doesn't change sending a request to service 2 while the test doesn't redirect requests from service 1 to service 2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).